# Value cannot be null error when attempting migration w/ .NET EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I am running into a "Value cannot be null" error when trying to run the following command
"dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -p Persistence -s API/"

I don't know if it matters or not, but I am following a class that is using .net 5.0 and I am using .net 6.0; but I have made modifications to the project as they have been recommended in the class to make it work for 6.0.

I have attached a screen shot of the Console Output here -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c1du.png)

One of the first lines of the console output seems to point to my Startup script

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPIv5", Version = "v1" });
        });
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("Default Collection")); <-- this line is referenced by the output.
        });
    }
```

I am not quite sure to do, and VSCode is not throwing any errors or warnings in regards to this code.

TIA

Comment: Are you sure that a config named `Default Collection` exists in your `appsetings.json`?

Comment: It does appear in `appsettings.Development.json` but not `appsettings.json` I will add that in and try it again

Comment: Update : I added default collection to `appsettings.json` but I am getting that error still

`  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default Connection": "Data source = reacitivites.db"
  },
`
is the code in my `appsettings.json` file

Comment: you are referencing "Default Collection" instead of "Default Connection"

Comment: @Eldar, that is exactly what the issue was. I changed Collection is Connection and the issue is resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment, so here's an answer.

---

Are you sure you don't have a simple spelling mistake?

The program is looking for a connection string with the name `Default Collection` (with two "l"s)

Your update comment states that you have `Default Connection` (with two "n"s) defined.

I would start by verifying that they match exactly.

Comment: Someone else commented this above and it turned out to be the issue, completely missed that typo.